# Tracking mousewheel events alongside KineticJS

Tags: javascript, kineticjs, mousewheel

The current scenario I need to solve, is rotating an image with the mousewheel.

As KineticJS does not have a specific hook for the mousewheel event (in that it's not a standard one anyway), I've used jquery-mousewheel to hook into the surrounding canvas, and KineticJS to store, on mouseover, the image that requires rotation.

On the mousewheel event, it checks if KineticJS has marked an image for rotation, it then goes ahead and rotates the image.

I'm not sure this is the best solution for the situation, as it doesn't take into account overlapped images (although I could probably prioritise the marking of 'active' shape to the topmost on the stack), or if this is even the most efficient solution.

Essentially:
on each shape-

```
 this.image.on("mouseover", function() { Engine.scrolling = _this.image;})
 this.image.on("mouseout",  function() { Engine.scrolling = null;})
```

on the outer container -

```
$("#DraftingBoard").mousewheel(function(event, delta, deltaX, deltaY){
        if(Engine.scrolling != null)
        {
            Engine.scrolling.rotateDeg(90);
            Engine.scrolling.getLayer().draw();
            event.preventDefault();
        }
```

Comment: Your solution looks fine.

Comment: What's the `Engine.scrolling` here?

Comment: Just a variable to store the image that has the cursor over it.